# I need to swap displays in Gnome 3 login screen

Tags: gnome

I use two monitors with Debian Jessie and Gnome 3. Everything works fine, but there is one cosmetic bug. However a bit annoying. I cannot figure out, how to swap the displays on Gnome login screen. I have the left side on right and the right one on left. I'm googling whole day, but nothing found...

Comment: You can do this either with xrandr or in your xorg.conf; do you have a preference?

Comment: I don't know exactly, how to create `xorg.conf` under Debian Jessie. But I thing, I tried both and none of these two things worked. Can you somehow tell me more, how to use the `xrandr`, please? (I mean, where to put its call. I tried it under my account and it worked - however - without having affected the login screen.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with using xrandr, you can edit the file `/etc/gdm3/Init/Display` and put in something like

```
xrandr --auto --output DVI-0 --mode 1440x900 --right-of DVI-1
```

(or whatever you found worked for you as a user)

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but it didn't affect the screens at all. I'm sorry... Probably Gnome 3.8 makes things other way.